# Не могу создать label-ы в цикле. Возникает ошибка, не могу разобраться

Tags: c#

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Требуется переменная конструктора.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">истинно, если управляемый ресурс должен быть удален; иначе ложно.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Код, автоматически созданный конструктором форм Windows

    /// <summary>
    /// Обязательный метод для поддержки конструктора - не изменяйте
    /// содержимое данного метода при помощи редактора кода.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        Label[] lb = new Label[Program.axisList[0].sumAxis];
        for (int i = 0; i < Program.axisList[0].sumAxis; i++)
        {
            lb[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            lb[i].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
            lb[i].AutoSize = true;
            lb[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 470);
            lb[i].Name = String.Format("lb{0}", i.ToString());
            lb[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 13);
            lb[i].TabIndex = 1;
            lb[i].Visible = true;
            lb[i].Enabled = true;
            Controls.Add(lb[i]);

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < Program.axisList[0].sumAxis; i++)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(lb[i]);
        }   

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < Program.axisList[0].sumAxis; i++)
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lb[i]; //
```

Comment: Хотите получить ответ, опубликуйте вопрос. Вопросы на сторонних ресурсах недолговечны

Comment: если Вы хотите получить ответ на свой вопрос то задайте его [правильно](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: не забудь указать какая ошибка выдаётся, хотя в данном случае это очевидно.

Comment: Если очевидно то можно наверно написать в чем ошибка, не так ли?

Comment: Ошибка в последней и предпоследней строке.

Answer (score 2):

1) Нельзя использовать оператор for вне тела методов, свойств. Да и не нужно в данном случае. Эти две строки можно смело стереть.

2) К объявленному в конструкторе массиву нельзя будет обратиться после завершения конструктора. Нужно почитать про области видимости. И перенести объявление массива в тело класса.

```
private Label[] lb;
```

Это собственно вместо того,на что ругается компилятор.
Инициализацию же можно оставить в конструкторе

```
lb = new Label[itemcount]; // вместо itemcount - нужное кол-во элементов
```

3)

> lb[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 470);

Все Label помещаются в одно место на форме, это наверняка не правильно.

4) Дважды вызывается Controls.Add(lb[i]) это тоже не правильно.

5) Стоит обратить внимание на коллекции, списки и т.д.

```
 private List<Label> lbs; 
 ...
 lbs = new List<Label>();    
 for (int i = 0; i < Program.axisList[0].sumAxis; i++)
 {
    Label lb = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    lb.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
    lb.AutoSize = true;
    lb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 470 + 2 * i * 13);
    lb.Name = String.Format("lb{0}", i.ToString());
    lb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 13);
    lb.TabIndex = 1;
    lb.Visible = true;
    lb.Enabled = true;
    Controls.Add(lb);
    lbs.Add(lb);
 }
```

У массивов есть недостаток, что при инициализации необходимо указать кол-во элементов